# UWP - move TextBlock above the phone keyboard

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

I need on my universal win10 app, one textblock be at the bottom of page and if keyboard is Visible , that textblock place above keyboard.

Is it possible ? How ?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33984936/windows-phone-keyboard-open-events-and-properties/33986288#33986288 or here full solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33984746/cant-scroll-till-the-end-of-the-results-when-the-keyborad-is-opened-windows-ph/33986428#33986428

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for solving this problem I used Commandbar and set my text block in the Content of CommandBar

```xml
<Page.BottomAppBar>
     <CommandBar >
          <CommandBar.Content>
              <TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock"/>
          </CommandBar.Content>
     </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```