# How to move the control/UI elements along with the keyboard in UWP

Tags: c#, keyboard, winrt-xaml, uwp

I'm wondering if there any solution that could make the app automatically adjust the controls position when the keyboard is activated. For example, in the image below, I want to make those four button on the screen move dependently with keyboard. When the keyboard is activated, buttons move to the center and move back when the keyboard is gone.

There might be some similar questions here but I couldnt see them in the search result, maybe they are using some different words on title so if this question is duplicated it will be appreciated if you guys could paste the link on comment or whereever.

[image: Images illustration]

Comment: there is solution for windows 8.1. try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33984746/cant-scroll-till-the-end-of-the-results-when-the-keyborad-is-opened-windows-ph/33986428#33986428 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33984936/windows-phone-keyboard-open-events-and-properties/33986288#33986288

Comment: Tks, they reall helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is you can listen to the Showing and Hiding event of the InputPane. In the event handler, you adjust your UI layout with respect to the keyboard.

For example, you can realign the button relative to the height of the keyboard.

For more information on InputPane, refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane.aspx

For dynamically align the UI layout example, refer to
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Keyboard-Events-Sample-866ba41c