# UWP - Align elemements according to keyboard

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I am creating an application where I have an input field and the button. Input field is on the top of the page and button is aligned to the bottom of the page. The problem is when I writing to input field, the keyboard pops up and hides the button that is defined at the bottom of the page. I want to align that button to keyboard, so when keyboard pops up, the button will be still visible.

Simple xaml code:

```
<TextBox x:Name="nameBox" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                 Margin="10,10,10,0" 
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                 PlaceholderText="Enter your name ..."  
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

        <Button
            x:Name="buttonDisplay"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Margin="10,10,10,10"
            Content="Display" 
            Click="buttonDisplay_Click"/>
```

Do you have any idea how to do it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a scrollviewer in your parent .

```
<Grid>
            <ScrollViewer>
                <TextBox x:Name="nameBox" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
             Margin="10,10,10,0" 
             TextWrapping="Wrap" 
             PlaceholderText="Enter your name ..."  
             VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

                <Button
        x:Name="buttonDisplay"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Margin="10,10,10,10"
        Content="Display" 
        Click="buttonDisplay_Click"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
```

is it helpful or you need something different ?

Answer (score 0):

There's some similar post in here [How to move the control/UI elements along with the keyboard in UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34649733/how-to-move-the-control-ui-elements-along-with-the-keyboard-in-uwp)

The idea is you can listen to the Showing and Hiding event of the InputPane. In the event handler, you adjust your UI layout with respect to the keyboard.

For example, you can realign the button relative to the height of the keyboard.

For more information on InputPane, refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane.aspx

There's a good example for dynamically align the UI layout, refer to https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Keyboard-Events-Sample-866ba41c